# Does anyone have a 'hello world' Debian package, for D source code?

Tags: debian, d, deb

I'm writing a D application which I want to package as a Debian package.

Does anyone know of a tutorial, or a skeleton package, to show me how to to do this for a D application?

Do I need to use autotools to build it?

Thanks,

Chris.

Comment: Just keep in mind that D in Debian is supposedly an older version. I am told.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source language of your project is rather unimportant. If it already has a Makefile, all you do in `debian/rules` is `make install` with the target paths set up where the packaging scripts expect (you might want to hack the main  Makefile to support the DESTDIR installation prefix). I would recommend Debhelper et al.; then your job is basically to fill in the debian/README.Debian and debian/copyright files, and comment out unnecessary stuff from debian/rules.

Answer (score 3):

IIRC, by default, D programs are stand alone; i.e. aside from system level .so dependencies (that shouldn't be included in the .deb) they *have no* dependencies. There are ways to make this not true but they are the exception. Consequently, a D 'hello world' binary, particularly from that standpoint of installing it, will look a lot like a C one.

The upshot of this is that, unless you are doing something strange, a C 'hello world' Debian package should be good enough to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

If you know of any packaged D application, you can get the package's source:

```
apt-get source the-package-name
```

Provided that you added a `deb-src` entry in your sources.list.

Comment: Yes, this will work apart from D apps being extremely thin on the ground.  If anyone knows the name of a Debian packaged D program, please let me know.

Comment: The package archive has a tag for "implementation language" but I got zero hits. Maybe that means there are none, or maybe that they have not been properly tagged. http://www.enricozini.org/2007/paper-debconf7/resources/

Comment: Oh, see also http://packages.debian.org/about/debtags#implemented-in::d -- there is currently no `implemented-in::d`.